# Stripe .Net - Getting cards from customer object

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve the list of card of a customer in Stripe.Net

In [their documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object), it is mentioned that the cards can be found under `Sources.data`.

However, I don't see the property ´data´ under sources.

[image]

Am I missing a cast or something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.

I have to cast it as a ´Source´, and then I have access to the Card object.

```
Stripe.Customer customer = _customerService.Get(id);
Stripe.Source source = customer.DefaultSource as Stripe.Source;
Stripe.SourceCard card = source.Card;
```